Problemas con subconsulta usando NOT IN en Amazon Redshift
1
Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta (que posee una subconsulta), la cual no me arroja ningún valor cuando la utilizo con NOT IN, pero cuando quito el NOT, sí me trae valores. Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue que no me trae ningún valor, porque efectivamente no hay un valor que cumpla con las condiciones, pero eso no es así, ya que hay valores que cumplen con las condiciones

Bueno, lo primero es agregar dicha consulta al post, para saber que estás haciendo bien y que no. Yo no me fio de palabras. Ahora, la clausula NOT IN es para buscar datos que no sean parte de un listado, es decir, un NOT IN (1,2,3), NO traería los valores 1, 2 y 3, de la variable que estamos consultando.

Es muy probable que tengas un NULL en el resultado de tu subconsulta. De ser así, nunca regresará nada cuando incluyas el NOT IN. Para corregirlo, puedes filtrar ese valor.
Te dejo el pseudocódigo para ejemplificar lo que digo.
SELECT columnas
FROM MiConsulta 
WHERE columna NOT IN( SELECT subcolumna
                      FROM subconsulta
                      WHERE subcolumna IS NOT NULL);

